# USB Flash drive too slow

Tags: windows-7, usb, performance, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

I've tried like 10 USB flash drives, and they are all slow :(

External USB hard-drives are much faster. For example transfer speeds on the WD passport are like 20 MB/sec compared to like 2 MB/sec on flash drives. And the latency on flash drives is huge. Computer often becomes unresponsive when accessing multiple file.

Here the spec say that it should reach the max. transfer speeds of the USB port:
http://www.lacie.com/products/product.htm?id=10462

That's 480Mbits/s aka 60 MB/sec, way more than 2 MB/sec...

Is there anything wrong with my computer or settings?
I'm running on Windows 7. And the computer is a Dell Vostro laptop

Comment: Sounds like the specifications of the passport is better then the flash drives.  I will be honest even for USB 2.0 devices they are slow.  Have you tried a power USB 2.0 hub to see if there is a difference in speed?

Comment: USB 2.0. My computer doesn't have USB 3.0

Comment: Are we talking about a USB 1.1, 2.0, or 3.0 port on the computer. (USB 1.1 is ~1.5MBps). :)

Comment: How do I verify that the port is USB 2.0?

Comment: @mry - Check the specification for your laptop.  While the link does indeed tell us the devices are USB 1.1/2.0 devices, update the question, to reflect that fact.

Comment: ok it's USB 2.0. It also has two USB 1.1 ports but they are in the back

Answer (score 0):

I would echo ramhound and bet its a hardware problem, however, you could also try the following and to see if its software/driver related.

Open up device manager and disable / re-enable the USB port devices. On my windows 7 machine it couldnt read my usb device but after I did this, it was able to read them again.